# Get bitmap buffer in Android

Tags: android, bitmap

I have a bmp file which is in black and white.
I get the bitmap in my code by using:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
```

I know that the bitmap contains a header, the data itself, and some other information. How can I get the data  component only from my `bmp` variable?

Additionally, I am curious as to why the buffer size of the bitmap is `width * length * 4`?

Answer (score 0):

To get data, use *getPixels*:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixels(int[], int, int, int, int, int, int)

Buffer size is `width * height * 4` only when bitmap has 32bit color space. In such case each color channel can have value from range [0:255] (8 bits = 1 byte), so four channels (reg, green, blue, alpha) take 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:
`Bitmap bitmap;
ByteBuffer buffer = new ByteBuffer(bitmap.getByteCount());
bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);`

Hope it helps.

David